# Update profile function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a function that check updates the users profile info. Currently, if I put |unique:users in the validator every time I try to update the profile info on the form it will not let me because a user (which is me) has my email. So I figured out the unique means that nobody, including the current user can have the email that is being updated.

So I need to compare the current auth email to the one in the database. If it matches then it is ok to update the profile info. I know this is simple but I am not sure how to implement it and if that is the right logic.

So where in this code would I post if (Auth::user()->email == $email){..update email...} http://laravel.io/bin/GylBV#6 Also, is that the right way to do this?

```
public function editProfileFormSubmit()
{

      $msg = 'Successfully Updated';
      $user_id = Auth::id();
      $user = User::find($user_id);
      $first_name = Input::get('first_name');
      $last_name = Input::get('last_name');
      $email = Input::get('email');
      $phone_number = Input::get('phone_number');
      $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'phone_number' => 'required'
                ));
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('edit-profile')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
        }else{
              if(Input::hasFile('picture')){
                $picture = Input::file('picture');
                $type = $picture->getClientMimeType();
                $full_image = Auth::id().'.'.$picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
                if($type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/jpg' || $type == 'image/jpeg'){
                  $upload_success =  $picture->move(base_path().'/images/persons/',
                    $full_image);
                  if($upload_success) {
                    $user->picture = $full_image;
                  } else {
                    $msg = 'Failed to upload picture.';
                  }
                }else{
                 $msg = 'Incorrect image format.';
                }
              }
            $user->first_name = $first_name;
            $user->last_name = $last_name;
            $user->email = $email;
            $user->phone_number = $phone_number;
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::route('invite')->with('global', $msg);
          }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worry not, Laravel has already considered this potential issue! If you take a look at [the docs for the unique validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique) you'll see that it can take some extra parameters. As it happens, you can give it an id to ignore when looking at the unique constraint. So what you need to do is work out the id for the current model to update and pass that in. In the case of updating a logged-in user's profile it's made easy by `Auth::id()` as you already have in your code.

```
$rules = [
    'email'      => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email,'.Auth::id()],
    'first_name' => ['required'],
    // etc...
];
```

Obviously I chose to use the array syntax for validation rules there, but you can do the same with the pip syntax too. In a less specific system (create-or-add in a crud `postSave` type action) you can still do it by simply dong something like `$model = Post::find($id)` and then if `$model` is null you're creating and you just use `'unique'` whereas if `$model` is not null, use `'unique:table,field,'.$model->getKey()`.

Comment: I tried this http://laravel.io/bin/PXd8v and get this error http://postimg.org/image/y33ekhz55/

Comment: @striker you forgot to add the comma before `Auth::id()`. Your code is `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'.Auth::id()` when it should be `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::id()`.

Comment: Though interestingly the error that's being displayed is using the id as the table name (``SELECT ... FROM `104` ``), whereas you'd expect from that code typo that it'll use the id as part of the column: ``SELECT ... FROM users WHERE `email104` = ...``

Comment: @alexrussell Thank you, that was it. I appreciate your help. Also, I would like to ask you if you have twilio experience with Laravel. If so, I need to find someone to pay to setup the sms on my app. If interested, just email me at the email in the error photo link I sent previously.

Comment: @striker I don't have experience, however you might want to try saving your money and having a go yourself using either the [Twilio official SDK for PHP](https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk) or one of the [many Laravel-specific Twilio packages](https://packagist.org/search/?q=twilio%20laravel) as I bet it'd be pretty easy.